# Do two monsters only emerge from the gate from the first mythos card in the Dunwich Horror setup?

Tags: arkham-horror

The Dunwich Horror expansion says in the setup:

> With five or more players, place two monsters on the gate indicated by the mythos card instead of one.

Is this something that only occurs in the very first mythos card's gate, or does this requirement for 5+ players occur elsewhere as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already in the base rules (top of page 10, Mythos phase, part C3):

> Exception: If there are five or more investigators playing, then draw and place two monsters instead of one.

The Dunwich rules are just saying explicitly that you *also* do this on the first mythos card of the game. That was already true in the base rules, since they said to do it as described above:

> Finally, the first player draws the top card of the mythos deck and resolves it as described in the Mythos Phase section of the rules.

It's just more explicit in Dunwich, in the same spirit as all the FAQ provided at the end of the rules.